# Windows 7 services default restore

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, services

I've changed my list of windows 7 services a bit too much, so if anyone would be kind enough to export theirs, id be very grateful.

PS. I'm on Home Premium x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black Viper has "default services" registry files available for all flavours of Windows 7, with extensive service-related information.

http://www.blackviper.com/Windows_7/servicecfg.htm

http://www.blackviper.com/Windows_7/registry.htm

Comment: Note, that's a very brief "intro" to the treasure trove of information compiled at Black Viper.  Surely a resource that should be bookmarked on any superuser's machine.  :)

Comment: I was unable to locate .reg files there btw.

Answer (score 1):

[Download Squad](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/09/28/restore-windows-services-to-defaults-web-app/) has the solution for you!

[Services Editor:](http://serviceseditor.com/) it gives you a text file with the default services, which you can use to restore!

> Microsofts Operating System is the
>   most advanced a#nd indeed one of the
>   best choices for people around the
>   world. However people often forget you
>   can get alot more speed from the
>   system by editing what Services are
>   running. Say for example you don't
>   have a printer, it's unlikely you will
>   need to print spooler service from
>   running. People often run the Windows
>   service editor when they first install
>   their new operating system - but they
>   have to edit each service one by one.
>
> This obviously takes alot of time and
>   indeed alot of effort.
>   ServicesEditor.com allows users to
>   quickly run down a list, choose what
>   action they want for the service and
>   then download a quick and easy
>   registry file which updates their PC's
>   running services! Simple.
>
> Our service manager is the easy way to
>   quickly edit the services that run on
>   your computer. We've made our service
>   safe to use - you can't disable
>   services which may result in the loss
>   of data. Although you should read up
>   about each service before you edit
>   it's default action you can use our
>   service manager is the knowledge that
>   we provide a easy way to mass edit
>   your Windows® services. Unlike the
>   Windows® default service editor you
>   can edit what services you run all at
>   once and then get a registry file to
>   quickly download and run. To get
>   started please select your operating
>   system!